# fadeOut is not working with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fade out a preloader after ajax call is completed but that preloader is not fading out raising an error : `Uncaught TypeError: preloader.fadeOut is not a function`

### Below goes my code

```
var preloader = document.getElementsByClassName('spinner')[0];
var _setheaderimg = function(response){
    preloader.fadeOut();
}
```

I tried out in stackoverflow but did not become fruitful.

Answer (score 0):

`fadeOut` is a jQuery methdod, but document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] returns a HTML element. You can't use jQuery methods on HTMLElements. Mixing plain javascript and jQuery should be avoided. So you need to use jQuery to select the element

```
$('.spinner').fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using jQuery here:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('spinner')[0];
```

thats vanilla JS. You need to use:

```
var preloader = $(".spinner");
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

use [Jquery](https://jquery.com/) library

```
$('.spinnter').first().fadeOut()
```

Answer (score 0):

By using pure javascript:

```
var preloader = document.getElementsByClassName('spinner');
   for(let fadeElement of preloader){
    var fadeEffect = setInterval(function () {
    if (!fadeElement.style.opacity) {
        fadeElement.style.opacity = 1;
    }
    if (fadeElement.style.opacity > 0) {
        fadeElement.style.opacity -= 0.1;
    } else {
        clearInterval(fadeEffect);
    }
  }, 200);
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/shahidali/pen/pKRWqG)